# Methods not declared after including

Tags: c, business-process-management, undeclared-identifier, aubio

I'm attempting to write a simple bpm calculation program in C with using the aubio library.

Everything seems to be going smoothly until I attempt to call upon `aubio_tempo_do` ([documentation](http://aubio.org/doc/tempo_8h.html#_details))

Unfortuantely, make provides me with the error:

```
‘aubio_tempo_do’ was not declared in this scope
```

which doesn't seem to make too much sense, considering the aubio library provides this function:

```
grep -r "aubio_tempo_do" /usr/local/include/aubio/
/usr/local/include/aubio/tempo/tempo.h:void aubio_tempo_do (aubio_tempo_t *o, fvec_t * input, fvec_t * tempo);
```

I attempt to include the tempo.h file in my header file, but alas the make routine continues to spout out the same error.

```
// header file
#include <aubio/aubio.h>
#include <aubio/tempo.h>
```

Any thoughts?

== Edit ===========

It should also be said that I've attempted:

```
#include <aubio/tempo/tempo.h>
```

With no luck :\

== Edit ===========

Output of g++ with the -E flag to check preprocesses: http://pastebin.com/mbFEysJ2

Source code can be found here: http://github.com/kellydunn/grover

Relevant source code excerpt: http://pastebin.com/KRmbZqg4

Comment: You can check the output of the preprocessor by adding the `-E` flag to your GCC command line (e.g. `gcc -E file.c`) and seeing if the necessary declarations are getting included or not.

Comment: After compiling with the -E flag, I checked the output and confirmed that the aubio_tempo_do method occurs before my code that requires the definition.

Comment: @kelly: Can you post a complete example of source code that demonstrates this problem?  Can you upload the output of `gcc -E` to pastebin.com?  What you've described can only be explained by a compiler bug, which I find to be highly unlikely.

Comment: sure, I'll make an edit to my original post

Comment: @Adam I will try and also cut up the relevant pieces of the source code and paste them into seperate pastebin pages

Comment: @kelly.dunn: Are you writing C or C++?  You can't mix the two, they are separate languages.  If you're writing C, remove the inclusion of `<cstdlib>` and use `<stdlib.h>` instead; if you're writing C++, change the source filename to `grover.cc`.  I suspect this may be related to your problem, although it might be something else.

Comment: as Adam says, don't compile C code with g++.

Comment: @Adam @Jens Thanks for help!  Both of your answers led me in the right direction.  Getting the project to compile strictly as C code helped me determine that there was actually a previous installation of the library functions on my machine.  it turns out I was calling deprecated methods: functions from `/usr/local/include/aubio` isntead of `/usr/include/aubio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the arguments you are passing to `aubio_tempo_do` have the right types?
`(aubio_tempo_t *o, fvec_t * input, fvec_t * tempo)`
I can't tell from the sample code.

If not, the compiler could be complaining that it doesn't see an overloaded version of the function with a signature that matches your arguments... (Although I would think there would be a more descriptive error message for that situation).

Comment: I thought this might have been the case, but after double checking my variable types, they do match the ones defined in <aubio/tempo.h>  (or more precisely <aubio/tempo/tempo.h>

Comment: Ultimately, your answer was the closest.  aubio_tempo_do was actually deprecated in terms of the libraries available from apt-get.  turns out this method was compiled and installed from source by another package.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you should include another file

```
#include <aubio/tempo/tempo.h>
```